# Is the Fréchet derivative of $F[u]=u^2$ given by $F'[u](h)=2u\cdot h$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

let $F:W\to W $ be a function.  $W=C(\Omega ) , \Omega .$  is bounded set in $R^n$

I try to understand how frechet derivative operates on arbitrary function h.

if for example $ F[u]=u^2 $  then can I say that for $h\in \Omega$,    $ F'[u](h)=2u\cdot h$?

($\cdot $   regular functions multiplication)

if I take another banach space instead of $W$ would the answer changed?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want $\Omega$ compact for $C(\Omega)$ to be a Banach space with the $L^\infty$ norm.

In that case, yes, $F'[u](h)=2uh$.  This is checked in a straightforward way from the definition of the Fréchet derivative:

$$\dfrac{\|F[u+h]-F[u]-2uh\|}{\|h\|}=\dfrac{\|h^2\|}{\|h\|}\leq\|h\|\to0.$$

If you take another Banach space, saying $F[u]=u^2$ might not make sense, but in any commutative Banach algebra the result is the same.  In a general Banach algebra, the result is $F'[u](h)=uh+hu$.